# Find a text in all solutions of Team Foundation 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I am a developer usin VS2012, I have the code in a Team Foundation 2010 (I am not the administrator of this).

I would like to find some text in all the solutions of muy own at the same time.

The "Find and Replace" tool does not help me because this finds just in one solution.

Could anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do a search on the TFS server directly. You need to check out all the code you want to look through to your local machine first.
Assuming you have done that then you can use the Find in Files option (usually <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>) and change the search scope to use a path or folder set by clicking the `...` button next to the *Look in* drop down.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy to use PowerShell and you have all the code files you want to search through on your local disk, you can run the following from the PowerShell ISE:

```
$locationToSeach = "C:\tfs\"
$pattern = "searchtext"

cd $locationToSearch

gci -recurse -include *.* | Select-String -pattern $pattern
```

If you want prettier formatting (e.g. for copy to Excel), pipe the above to:

```
Format-Table @{Name='Path'; Expression={$_.Path}; Width=150}, @{Name='Line'; Expression={$_.Line -replace '^\s+', ''}; Width=200}
```